# On the speed of light being "algebraically infinite"

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, group-theory, mathematics

Browsing the math stackexchange recently, I found this exercise which caught my interest.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793358/

The exercise takes the group of real numbers $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$ equipped with the standard operation of addition, and shows that it is isomorphic to the group consisting of the real open interval $(-1,1)$ when equipped with a new binary operation $*$.

What's interesting is that the binary operation $*$ is precisely the composition of velocities in special relativity, and this is the natural operation to put on an interval of real numbers if one wanted to "collapse" the real numbers as a group.

That is, the group $((-1, 1), *)$ is the group that describes the composition of linear velocities, taking $c = 1$. The fact that $((-\infty, \infty),+) \cong ((-c,c),*)$ seems to suggest that the speed of light is algebraically analogous to infinity regarding real numbers.

My question is along the lines of: is this thought of in physics, or useful in physics? Does it give a physical intuition here? My background is in math, and I think my reaction is probably very common. It would be natural to wonder about the algebraic structures equipped with this binary operation, so I'm sure this has some material somewhere, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Mathematically isn't this just using the isomorphism given by $x \mapsto \tanh x$. Physically this corresponds to the idea of [rapidities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity).

Comment: @jacob1729 That's what I was looking for, thank you!